# what's the impact of balancing of sharding?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

After create a sharded document, when data are not evenly distributed, then mongodb will balance the data. During the balancing process, what's the impact to database operation? First it won't block read, but will it black write for a short time? Per the document, it only says balancing will make backup inconsistent, so during backup, we should disable auto balance. Any other things we need to consider for balancing process？